# clear output in telnet

Tags: java, telnet

Is there any way to make a telnet app to clear the output client-side (using Java Socket connection + Buffers)? For example, the program queries the connected user for login and password and when they've succeeded logging in, I do `cls` for Windows or `clear` for Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The telnet application is a terminal emulator. In really old times the only way to communicate with a computer was by using a terminal with a pure text based screen and a keyboard. The terminal sent everything you typed to the computer. The computer sent characters back that was printed on the screen. Just like telnet.
DEC created a series of terminals called VT52, VT100 etc. They was able to interpret special control sequences so that the computer could give more fancy instructions to the terminal. These control sequences was standardized by ANSI and is now called ANSI escape codes. Terminal emulators that understand the VT100 escape codes are called VT100 terminal emulators.

You may look up the ansi escape codes on wikipedia and other places. They all start with the character codes for escape and [ followd by the control characters. The control characters for clearing the screen is "2J".
So, what you need to do is sending this string from your server to the telnet client:

```
myOutputStream.print("\u001B[2J");
myOutputStream.flush();
```

You may send other control characters as well. Try "\u001B[7m" to reverse the screen.

Comment: BTW, do you know of any site that has these escape codes? Wikipedia isn't helping much this time...

Answer (score 1):

On the Linux side, clear simply issues some terminal control characters to tell it to clear the screen. For VT terminals, that's `Esc]2J`. Not sure if Windows would support something similar.

Comment: But how can I call the clear from the server side? Not by just sending a string, that's for sure.

Comment: Yes, you can just by sending a string :)

Comment: That's how VT escape sequences are done, though. It's just some output to the terminal, using a literal escape character (ascii 27) to preface the VT commands.

Comment: Well, sending the string `cls` doesn't work for Windows. Not critical, but still kinda sucks...

Comment: That's because 'cls' is a command built into cmd.exe/command.com. The string by itself does nothing. VT is the generic name given to oldschool terminals supplied by DEC. VT escape sequences were the special control codes used to manipulate cursor position, clear the screen, etc... Over the years the sequences became defacto standards and are still in widespread use, even though the hardware terminals are all but completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling blank lines is the only way I can think of in Java if you need to support windows.

Comment: Does that mean Linux supports it?

Comment: Only in the form mentioned below by Marc B, as far as I know.